# How to control openshift rollout (CI/CD pipeline)?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, openshift

We've been using a deployment config with image change trigger so that when a new image appears in the configured image stream a new rollout would be triggered. This has worked relatively well, but now we got a new challenge. The pipeline should wait for the rollout to complete and reflect success/failure as the job outcome.

We've figured so far to pause rollouts while the image is being built. Then once built, unpause the rollouts and rollout explicitly, then wait for rollout to complete:

```
# To work well with previously auto triggered deployments, pause rollouts if present
oc rollout pause dc "$SOURCE_NAME" || true

# apply deployment config
# TODO: Pass all the template parameters
oc process -f delivery-automation/openshift/jdk-service-template.yml -p "SOURCE_NAME=$SOURCE_NAME" -p "IMAGE_NAME=$IMAGE_NAME" | oc apply -f - --validate
# tag the correct image version as latest
# https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/promoting_applications.html
oc tag "$OC_PROJECT_STORAGE/$IMAGE_NAME:$SOURCE_VERSION" "$IMAGE_NAME:latest"

# gogogogo
oc rollout resume dc "$SOURCE_NAME" || true
#new deployment with latest image
oc rollout latest "$SOURCE_NAME"
#check for rollout is success
oc rollout status "dc/$SOURCE_NAME" --watch
```

This almost works, except it still triggers deployments on image change which then fails on `oc rollout latest` because another deployment is already in progress.

**EDIT:** The command `oc rollout resume` actually starts a rollout on image change!

We've tried to modify the trigger as well not to trigger automatically to no avail:

```
  triggers: 
    - type: ImageChange
      imageChangeParams:
        automatic: false
        containerNames:
          - ${SOURCE_NAME}
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: '${IMAGE_NAME}:latest'
```

We've also tried to remove the image change trigger altogether, but then the rollout fails because it cannot resolve the actual image.

Comment: If something else is controlling when the new deployment should occur after image stream is updated, you would usually remove the whole `ImageChange` trigger completely from the resource definition, rather than pause it, and rely on the manual trigger only.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton, I've tried that, but it is through the trigger that openshift resolves which image to use. Without the trigger, rollout fails with Imge pull backoff error. It is not able to figure the image out. I would not be able to rollout simply specifying an image stream, but would have to provide full image path which is something I want to avoid in order to keep all environments the same.

Comment: You might look at using `oc set image` to update image in deployment before triggering rollout.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sloppy solution for now and I'll be happy if someone proposes a better alternative:

```
# reconfigure service and deployment
- oc process -f service-template.yml -p "SOURCE_NAME=$SOURCE_NAME" -p "IMAGE_NAME=$IMAGE_NAME" | oc apply -f - --validate
# tag current version as latest
- oc tag "$OC_PROJECT_STORAGE/$IMAGE_NAME:$SOURCE_VERSION" "$IMAGE_NAME:latest"
# cancel any pending rollout, last one wins!
- oc rollout cancel dc "$SOURCE_NAME" || true
# cancel any pending rollout, make sure cancel completed
- oc rollout status "dc/$SOURCE_NAME" --watch || true
# trigger new rollout
- oc rollout latest "$SOURCE_NAME" -o json | jq -r '"Rollout started - " + (.status.latestVersion | @text)'
# follow up on latest rollout
- oc rollout status "dc/$SOURCE_NAME" --watch
```

This leaves me with some residual cancelled rollouts, but functionally, it is satisfactory.